# JQuery .Load HTML not Formatting Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Afternoon StackOverflow!

I seem to have an issue. When I use:

```
$("#specificDIV").load("new.html")
```

The HTML content gets placed into the div, but the CSS and JS doesn't work and gets formatted wrong. I have items like a slider and words, but they seem to overflow outside of the divs, aren't as preserved as the original fonts and the slider doesn't even function.

I have tried copying in the header as the same as the original html inside of new.html to see if the CSS and JS have to be referenced and still nothing. I have also seen that the .load is also deprecated and used:

```
$("#specificDIV").on("load","new.html")
```

and still broke exactly like before on the first try, but now when I call it I get an error:

> load Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string "new.html"

which leads me back to the deprecated load function, which isn't apparently very cool to do.

How do I fix the non formatting .load() issue and the .on() guid error?
 Anyways thanks for reading up to this far and in advanced.

edit: Here's some screenshots at what is happening.

[image: What's happening right now]

[image: eWhat should be happening...]

Answer (score 1):

Two items:

> $("#specificDIV").on("load", "new.html") doesn't work.

Nor should it. This is really saying "when $("#specificDIV") receives a 'load' **event** execute the string "new.html". The confusions comes because JQuery has two `.load()` methods. The above `.on()` style replaces the older `.load()` style.

You're wanting to use the other `.load()` method, which is fine. However, jQuery documentation says:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Is your CSS and JS within a `head` element in your retrieved file? If so, move them out of `<head>` .

Comment: But on the other hand for the second fix, I tried placing the script src's into the new.html itself (got rid of the head, html, and body tags) and also tried placing the script src and links at the beginning and end of the body of the original html page with the same results. I am beginning to think there's an issue with the div console class.

Comment: With the second fix, can you observe that the JS and CSS are indeed loaded into the DOM? (they should be). If so, then it depends on your specific JS and CSS. Is the JS written to execute immediately, or is it waiting for an even which will never happen (like 'load').

Comment: Hmmm... well the event .load() has to happen so that the new.html loads into the div id="console". After the load function, the new.html gets placed into the div id="console" and replaces the form that was in there prior. I know that the bootstrap CDN is working because of the fact that the buttons didn't lose format.

Comment: Right, but after you've replaced the form, is there any code which should be run _on_the_form_ to get it to work correctly? (Like event listeners on these new elements) If so, either those listeners need to be initialized, or you use a delegate form of jquery ... `$(body).on('click', '#console button', function() {})`.

Comment: Nope no other code on the HTML that loads after the first load. It should make sense that if I add in the script src for bootstrap and relinking my css files in new.html should work, but it doesn't... hmm there must be a different way...

Comment: Okay, so actually I did try and force a CSS file and it did make changes, but the items like the slider and the color bar kept overflowing outside of the div just like the picture above. This must mean there's something that's not being preserved right...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/new.html',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#specificDIV').html(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, but I'm still getting the same result... :/ I'm going to add some pictures to the original post to see if that helps with what's going on.

Comment: I was trying to use them both but I couldn't get them to work... :/